# Select a specific column and all columns on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How could I write this "SELECT COLUMN, * FROM TABLE" in Oracle. I don't have any problem when I use that syntax on Sql Server or MySQL, but on Oracle appears the message **"ORA-00936"**

```
Oracle DataBase

SELECT COLUMN, * FROM TABLE 

ORA-00936
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <table_name>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alias the column name and the '*'

MPOWEL01> Select empid empno, a.* from t1 a;

```
 EMPNO      EMPID CORR_ACTION_TYPE CORR_ACTI
```

---

```
  7654       7654              123 18-FEB-19
  7654       7654              456 07-APR-19
  7654       7654              789 07-MAY-19
  7521       7521              123 10-MAR-19
  7521       7521              256 18-JUN-19
```

5 rows selected.